# Unable to deploy multiple contracts to arbitrum nova via foundry

Tags: contract-deployment, foundry, arbitrum

I've written a script to deploy multiple contracts to arbitrum nova via foundry enviroment

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "../lib/forge-std/src/Script.sol";

import "../src/Bob.sol";
import "../src/BobRanks.sol";
import "../src/BobManager.sol";
import "../src/BobChannel.sol";

contract BobDeploy is Script {
    
    address public dummyAddress = address(0);
    address public arbSysAddress = address(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000064);

    function run() external {
        uint256 deployerPrivateKey = vm.envUint("PK_A1M");
        vm.startBroadcast(deployerPrivateKey);
        //create contracts
        BobRanks ranks = new BobRanks();
        BobManager manager = new BobManager(dummyAddress, address(ranks));
        Bob bob= new Bob(address(manager), arbSysAddress);

        //set correct contract addresses
        manager.changeRhascauContract(address(bob));
        ranks.changeBobManagerContract(address(manager));

        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Using the command below to launch the script

```
forge script script/BobDeploy.s.sol:BobDeploy --rpc-url https://here-was-my-rpc-url/ --broadcast --with-gas-price 19999926 --skip-simulation
```

After running the command I receive prompt

> "Transaction failure"

. Previously I was trying to deploy without skipping the simulation, however i received error

> intrinsic gas too low

Anyone has any idea on what is wrong here? The deployment works fine on arbitrum mainnet and arbitrum goerli.